# In Expo, my APK file is giving me an "index.android.bundle" error

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

I have completed my Expo project and obtained the output for Android. When I install the output I received as an APK on my phone, I encounter this error.

Since I checked the isDevice status in the Notification permission section, my application, which opens smoothly on the emulator, does not open on real devices.

What are your suggestions for me to solve this issue?

[image]

eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the exception/error handler returns this error and you serialize the error object to be shown in Alert. This error message is not enough to debug the issue. Try error monitoring service for more insight on error in production - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/

Comment: With Sentry the project doesn't work at all :)

Comment: Reproducing issues will require an in-depth understanding of your codebase. You can find my contact on StackOverflow profile so we can have a 1-1 meeting if that help.